# How to make sure that Data are saved in Parse.com and ready to be retrieved Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com for developing a small application.

In a couple of actives i'm inserting values to a Class, and Immediately after that i'm Retrieving the values inserted from the previous activity, it's showing Error, it seems that it takes some seconds to save before being able to retrieve.

so i'm asking how can I know that the saved has been completed with Parse. is there any callback function which can let me know, so I would be able to retrieve that information

here is the code where i'm saving values

```
            ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("test");
            query.whereEqualTo("user", user.getUsername());

            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

              public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {



                if (object == null) {

                } else {
file = new ParseFile("profil.png", image);
        file.saveInBackground();
       object.put("name", nom.getText().toString());

       object.put("Profil",file);
       object.saveInBackground();
}
```

Comment: First of all: what is the error you are getting? To answer your question, yes there are callbacks for save etc. when you call saveInBackground pass in a SaveCallback as the parameter which will be called once the object has been saved. If there is no exception (passed into the SaveCallback) you can be sure that the data is on the server and can be retrieved.

Comment: If i wait 5 to 10 seconds before executing the activity where retrieving data, it works fine, but when the activity is executed right away, it doesn't, can you give an example of SaveCallback

Comment: You are probably calling saveInBackground and then show the next activity without waiting for the save to finish. Here is an example that should work http://pastebin.com/zmQaz0Kc

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question

https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/SaveCallback.html

thank to Bjorn Kaiser